# "Equivalent function" search (function usage deduction)

Tags: haskell

When coding, we write code using our own knowledge about available machinery. That knowledge is (obviously) partial. Would be great some tool (e.g. like `pointfree`) say to us if exists some function equivalent to our code. That work looks be, in general, NP-complete (subgraph isomorphism) but may be practical in some cases.

I'm thinking in some like:

1. search code signature (and perhaps sub-search) using Hoogle.
2. test equivalence using some proof tooling or empirically using `Test.QuickCheck`.

Example:

```
> :t getSum . foldMap Sum
getSum . foldMap Sum :: (Num c, Foldable t) => t c -> c
> :t sum
sum :: (Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a
>
```

Then, when writes the former, the later is suggested automatically. Using `pointfree` style:

```
$ search-equivalence 'getSum . foldMap Sum'
sum
```

Exists some tooling doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Hlint](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint), it really works well.

There is a [plugin](https://atom.io/packages/linter-hlint) for [atom](https://atom.io/).
I've been using it for a while and It really helps, you can even learn from it sometimes.

Comment: I think is a good (util) answer but I can't get suggested reduction (testing `echo 'f = getSum . foldMap Sum' | hlint -`). Can you show some similar behavior?

Comment: @josejuan Is the only thing I knew about that more or less fit in for your question, I havent used it myself, just the atom plugin. Cant go further my friend.